# ObjectiveDropboxOfficial cannot authorize my app when dropbox app is installed in same device

Tags: ios, ipad, dropbox-sdk

I integrated ObjectiveDropboxOfficial SDK of dropbox into my app. I followed the dropbox tutorial provided and was able to authorize the app and do further dropbox operations like upload and download.
It worked well.

But if the same app is installed in a device which already has dropbox app installed, then the app is unable to get authorize from dropbox.
When my app call following code.

```
[DBClientsManager authorizeFromController:[UIApplication sharedApplication] controller:[[self class] topMostController] openURL:^(NSURL *url) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];}];
```

The app goes to background and dropbox app gets open asking to allow access for dropbox.

[image: Screenshot]

When I tap "Allow", it goes back to my app and nothing happens. So, i again try to access dropbox in my app, it again goes to dropbox app and again ask for authorization. So, my app never gets authorized with dropbox.

Is there anyone, who faced similar problem while integrating ObjectiveDropboxOfficial SDK? Is there any cure for this?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because I took a clone of master branch of dropbox SDK repository from github. This brancch i guess would be in development. I was supposed to download a release version of dropbox SDK from release tags of the repository.

I actually learnt, always download release version tagged source code rather than cloning or downloading master or other development branch of repository from github.